# jTable index is wrong

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When I select the row in jtable, it always returns `-1` as a table row index.

This is how I fill the data to jtable:

```
private void addResultToRecTable(DefaultTableModel dtm, ArrayList<RecipeModule> al) {

    if (al != null) {
        int rowCount = dtm.getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            dtm.removeRow(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            String[] recArray = {al.get(i).getRecID(), al.get(i).getRecName(), al.get(i).getRecCategory(), al.get(i).getRecQty(), al.get(i).getRecUnit()};
            dtm.addRow(recArray);

        }
    }
```

This is how I pass the data to the `addResultToRecTable()` method:

```
ArrayList<RecipeModule> al = RecipeController.searchRecipes(txtRepSearchName.getText(), txtRecSearchCate.getText());
addResultToRecTable(recDefaultTableModel, al);
```

After I filled the data to table. I selected a row in the table and printout selected row index. Then I got this error.

```
private void tableRecSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {   
    try{
        int selectedRow = tableRecIngredients.getSelectedRow();
        System.out.println(selectedRow);
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. Any advice?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exception stack trace, so people can see where the exception is happening?

Comment: Why don't you have it select the row from what is clicked?

Answer (score 4):

```
private void tableRecSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
```

I have no idea what that event is. Maybe the row selection hasn't completed yet.

If you want to know when the row selection has changed then add a `ListSelectionListener` to the table.

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more information and examples.

```
    //int rowCount = dtm.getRowCount();
    //for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    //    dtm.removeRow(0);
    //}
```

To remove all the rows from the table model you can just use:

```
dtm.setRowCount(0);
```